# Android: SharedPreferences with longs

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, long-integer

I want to save a time from a TimePickerDialog to sharedpreferences from my settings menu. I then want to retrieve this data when from another fragment.  The time is stored as a long.

In the setting menu - when the positive button is pressed

```
SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("TIME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

     SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(
             "any_prefname", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

     Editor editor = pref.edit();
     editor.putLong("key_name", 8);
     editor.commit();
```

In the fragment:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(
                 "any_prefname", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Long longValue = pref.getLong("key_name", 0);

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Hi " + longValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

The problem is that the value "8" that I saved is note being shown in the toast from the fragment.  The value being used is the 0.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using the same key.  When saving you used "time", when loading you used "key_name".  You need to use 1 name.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to delete that bit - I will edit the code but it still doesn't work